# ASP.NET Form Data to XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, forms

So I'm trying to create a XML file as output which needs to be filled with the data from the input form.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">

       <form method="POST" action="/xml/index_action">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="minuten">Aantal minuten</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="minuten" autofocus placeholder="Vul het aantal minuten">
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verzenden</button>
       </form> 
   </div>
</div>
```

and in my Controller I convert the string into a integer

```
public ActionResult index_action(FormCollection collection)
    {

        string iMinuten = Convert.ToString(collection["minuten"]);


        Int64 number = Int64.Parse(iMinuten);

        Int64 i = number / 60;
        Int64 u = number - (number / 60 * 60); ;

        ViewBag.uren = i;
        ViewBag.minuten = u;


        return View("~/Views/Xml/Index.cshtml");

    }
```

But I can't seem to find anything that can convert my input into XMl even if it's one line of xml content.

Comment: What do you mean - convert to xml?

Comment: @teovankot I want the text which is the input of the form to be converted to xml to use it elsewhere

Comment: You enter xml in input? Or what? I can see now you enter `int` and parse it

Comment: @teovankot that parse is there so that my string becomes an int. This little program is to covert minutes into hours and minutes. But I want the output to outputed in a XML file

Comment: output of what? What do you call output? `number` variable? Just serialize it

Answer (score 0):

The raw text of the input just be thrown into a new file and saved as an .xml file with UTF8 encoding.

Comment: That I understand but I can't seem to find the right method(s)

Answer (score 0):

xml docwriter from Ms xml6 might be worth importing.